# How do I iterate though an array of objects with keys and values in react and render them in the JSX( Both keys and Values)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

The below code gives me the grouped data as shown in the image.
When I iterate through it and log the result to the console, I get the data but get blank html table when iterating the same way as I did to log the data in the console.

Here's how I'm grouping the data:

```
const finalGroup = sortedOrderItems && _.groupBy(sortedOrderItems, "deliveryDate");

let result = _.map(_.values(finalGroup), arr => _.groupBy(arr, 'deliveryDate'))

console.log("final grouping:",result)
```

[image]

```
 let tableData =     
     
        result && result.map(res=>{

                        Object.keys(res).map((key, index) => {   

                          <TableRow style={{backgroundColor:'#E6E6FA', textAlign:'center'}}>
                                  <TableCell colSpan={9} style={{backgroundColor:'#E6E6FA'}}>{key}</TableCell>
                          </TableRow>      
      
                      res &&  res[key].map((object) => {  

                                      return      <TableRow style={{backgroundColor:'#FAFAFA', textAlign:'center'}}>
                                            <TableCell style={{fontSize:'17px'}}> <img src={object.product.productImage} style={{border:'1px solid #DEDBDB',height:'50px',marginTop:'1px', marginLeft:'2px', width:'50px'}} alt={object.name} /></TableCell>
                                            <TableCell ><div style={{ wordWrap:'break-all'}}>{MOMENT(object.deliveryDate).tz(timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm A')}</div></TableCell>
                          
                                            <TableCell ><div style={{width:'200px', wordWrap:'break-all'}}>{object.name}</div></TableCell>
        
                                            <TableCell><span style={{marginLeft:'-40px'}}>{object.unitName}</span></TableCell>
                                            <TableCell><span style={object.status == 'BACK_ORDER' ||  object.status == 'UNAVAILABLE' || object.status == 'OUT_OF_STOCK' ? {color:'red',marginLeft:'-35px'} : {color:'green', marginLeft:'-35px'} }>{object.status}</span></TableCell>
                                            <TableCell><span style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{regionID && regionID == 1050 ? <span>&#36;</span> : regionID && regionID == 1000 ? <span>&#x20b9;</span>: ''}{object.unitPrice}</span></TableCell>
                                            <TableCell><span style={{textAlign:'center'}}>{regionID && regionID == 1050 ? <span>&#36;</span> : regionID && regionID == 1000 ? <span>&#x20b9;</span>: ''}{object.totalPrice}</span></TableCell>
                                            <TableCell><span style={{}}>{object.quantity}</span></TableCell>                                                        
                                        
                                          <TableCell>
                                            <div style={{float:'right', marginLeft:'-65px'}}>
                                                <FormControl variant="outlined" style={{width:'202px', float:'right'}}>
                                                    <InputLabel id="status">Update Item Status</InputLabel>
                                                    <Select
                                                      style={{height:'44px',textAlign:'center', margin:'7px'}}
                                                      native
                                                      id= 'status'
                                                      value={OrderItemStatus.status}
                                                      onChange={(event, id)=>{handleStatusChange(event, object.id)}}
                                                      label="Update Order Status"
                                                                                            
                                                    >
                                                    <option aria-label="None" value="" />
                                                    {statuses.map((stat, index)=>{
                                                        return(<option id={index} key={index} value={stat}>{stat}</option>
                                                        )
                                                    })}
                                                    </Select>
                                                </FormControl>
                                              </div>
                                          </TableCell>
                                        
                                        </TableRow>
                                     
      
      
                          });
      
                  })
      
                      
        
         })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I hope you did not forget to return `tableData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have an array of objects where each object is a collection of key-value pairs where the values are the nested arrays you want to map. Don't forget to return the JSX you are mapping.

```
const tableData = result && result.map(res=> {
  return Object.entries(res).map(([key, value], index) => {
    return (
      <Fragment key={key}>
        <TableRow style={{backgroundColor:'#E6E6FA', textAlign:'center'}}>
          <TableCell colSpan={9} style={{backgroundColor:'#E6E6FA'}}>{key}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        {value.map((object) => {
          return (
            <TableRow style={{backgroundColor:'#FAFAFA', textAlign:'center'}}>
              ...
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
      </Fragment>
    );
  })
})
```

Comment: wow!! Thank you very much @Drew Reese . You are a life saver.. Appreciated a lot. This is exactly what I needed.